# cakephp no get data to edit

Tags: php, cakephp, get, edit

I work on project someone already did it, but need to update some fileds on form
I want added 2 columns  in database for ex( id,title,body,keyword,description)

```
<legend><?php __('Edit Section'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('id');
        echo $this->Form->input('title');
        echo $this->Form->input('body');
        echo $this->Form->input('keyword');
        echo $this->Form->input('description'); 
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit', true));?>
```

i added keyword,description they new columns.

on the edit.ctp page

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Section');?>
<fieldset>
```

the title & body show data, the new textboxs keyword & descrioption now get data from database

here the edit function on the controlr

```
function edit($id = null) {
        if (!$id && empty($this->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid section', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        if (!empty($this->data)) {
            if ($this->Section->save($this->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The section has been saved', true));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The section could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
            }
        }
        if (empty($this->data)) {
            $this->data = $this->Section->read(null, $id);
        }
    }
```

so why it show only title & body & the new textboxes no work

Comment: first of all, did you altered the new columns in the database?second, what do you mean the new textboxes do not work? They do not appear on the page or they don't have any values?

Comment: yes i added the new 2 columns (keyword,description) .I mean the textboxs no have any values.the old textboxes (title,body) have its values normal.

Comment: Make sure you have at least cleared the model cache (`app/tmp/cache/models/`).

Comment: This is very normal to happen. Since your newly altered columns have no values (unless you did that too), nothing will be shown inside the respective textboxes

Comment: thanks ndm  you are right. it work now it needed to clear the  cache (app/tmp/cache/models/).

Comment: thanks Cris Sawfish for u too . I already added values on the new altered columns . it work now as ndm said the soultion.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable your debug in "app/Config/core.php" Configure::write('debug', 2);
Its automatically updates your cache model